# Solr query to SQL query

Tags: java, sql, parsing, solr, lucene

I want to write Java code which will parse a Solr query and convert it into its equivalent SQL query. Can anyone please tell me the approach or algorithm to do the same?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/bbejeck/sql-for-lucene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Solr and SQL do not have equivalent query syntax, or really even a comparable information retrieval model. It's not uncommon to use both a lucene index *and* a SQL database. They do different things.

For a concrete example, one of the core building blocks of a lucene query is `SHOULD` clauses, which SQL simply does not have any equivalent for. The following query logic could not be replicated in SQL:

```
+term1 term2
```

The closest you could get would be to search for term1, and simply throw out term2.